# Firebase deploy is deploying my source folder unencrypted

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

### ISSUE:

My Firebase Deploy is not deploying just the minified file, but also my raw source files and folders.

**Details:**

I'm using the `firebase deploy` command, and in my `firebase init`, I mentioned my folder name(`deploy` folder name) that's supposed to be deployed.

But when I build my project with `npm run build` and deploy the project after transferring it to `deploy` folder, for some reason it also deploys my src folder with all the raw data.

**Folder Structure and `firebase.json`:**
[image]

**Inspecting my hosted site**
[image]

For some reason, I think I'm doing it wrong , as even my `node_modules` are being uploaded, I tried to add `./src` in **ignore**

Comment: It might just look like `src` is being deployed because of source maps.

Comment: @abraham, I think so.  Is there a way to stop deploying src?

Comment: If what you are seeing is the source map you have to turn off building source maps when you build/compile for deploy. You'll have to read the documentation for the build tool you're using.

Comment: hi @DhavalJardosh, could you solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deploying for Firebase Hosting, you don't specify which folder you want to deploy.  firebase.json contains the name of the folder you want to deploy, and almost everything in it is deployed by default.  If you want to exclude additional files, you'll have to figure that.  [Read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify_files_to_deploy) for details on how to do that.

> The ignore attribute specifies the files to ignore on deploy.
>   It can take glob pattern the same way that Git handles .gitignore.
>
> The following are the default values for the files to ignore:
>
> ```
> "hosting": {
>   "ignore": [
>     "firebase.json",  // the Firebase configuration file (this file)
>     "**/.*",  // files with a leading period should be hidden from the system
>     "**/node_modules/**"  // contains dependencies used to create your site but not run it
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Doug, thank you for the help, but for some reason it still shows in my inspect. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @Doug Is it possible to specify the ignore files from CLI? The reason for asking is because, In my project(built with express) there are some functions which don't need complete functions/src folder to get pushed.